# Destructor getting called on assigning the deleted pointer to a new object

Tags: c++

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string.h>

    using namespace std;

    class A {
            public:
            A () {cout<<" A\n";}
            virtual ~A () {cout<<" ~A\n";}
            };

    class B : public A {
            public:
            B () :A() {cout<<" B\n";}
            virtual ~B() {cout<<" ~B\n";}
            };

    int main (int, char *[]) {
            A *ap = new B;
            delete ap;
            A b = *ap;
            return 0;
            }
```

Output is :

```
  A

  B

 ~B

 ~A
```

Why the last destructor of A is getting called for A b = *ap
Why not the constructor for A is getting called here  ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 5):

You're running into **undefined behavior** and **anything** can happen.

After you call `delete ap;` it's illegal to dereference it:

```
delete ap;
A b = *ap;
```

That aside, you do know the destructors are called in reverse order of inheritance, right? Meaning that if you delete a `B`, the base class destructor `~A` will also be called.

Also note that if it were valid (which it isn't), `A b = *ap;` would call the compiler-generated *copy-constructor*, not your constructor.